# re-frame: Input :on-change reset! doesn't change input value

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I'm playing around with the `re-frame` framework.

---

In the code below, I am having trouble with updating the input value when the user types something in:

```
(defn measurement-input [{:keys [amount unit path]}]
  (let [amt (atom amount)]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:input {:type "text"
                :value @amt
                :on-change #(reset! amt (-> % .-target .-value))}]
       [:input {:type "button"
                :value unit}]])))
```

The input value will not change until until I change `:value` to `:defaultValue`. I am pretty sure the above example closely mirrors `Reagent`'s input example.

---

In the code below, I am trying to do two things when the user updates the input value. I'm trying to `reset!` the input's value as well as `dispatch` the value to an event handler. I've wrapped up both of these function calls in a `do` call.

Also of note is that in the code below, the user is able to update the value in the text field.

```
(defn measurement-input [{:keys [amount unit path]}]
  (let [amt (atom amount)]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:input {:type "text"
                :value @amt
                :on-change (do #(reset! amt (-> % .-target .-value))
                                (re-frame/dispatch [:update-value @amt]))}]
       [:input {:type "button"
                :value unit}]])))
```

In the javascript console, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null  template.cljs?rel=1435381284083:101
```

---

Any help is appreciated everybody!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daniel Kersten over at the ClojureScript Google Groups, explained to me why the code snippets weren't working. The link to the post is [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojurescript/1OqbAOEjXxM/54VQkabkedEJ).

---

1st code snippet

`reagent` overrides `clojure`'s atom with it's own implementation. `re-frame`'s `views.cljs` doesn't refer to this by default. Once you refer to `reagent`'s version of `atom`, things will work.

At the top of the `views.cljs` file, change this:

```
(ns performance-tracker.views
    (:require [re-frame.core :refer [subscribe dispatch]]))
```

to:

```
(ns performance-tracker.views
    (:require [reagent.core  :as reagent :refer [atom]]
              [re-frame.core :refer [subscribe dispatch]]))
```

---

2nd code snippet

`:on-change` expects a function. I was passing in a `do` block. Simply wrapping the `do` block inside a function fixed the error. See below for the correct code:

```
(defn measurement-input [{:keys [amount unit path]}]
  (let [amt (atom amount)]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:input {:type "text"
                :value @amt
                :on-change #(do (reset! amt (-> % .-target .-value)) ;; argument literal, %, is the event passed in the function callback
                            (re-frame/dispatch [:update-value @amt [:measurements path :amount]]))}]
       [:input {:type "button"
                :value unit}]])))
```